# Azure DevOps Excel Integration Not Working

Tags: excel, azure-devops, azure-devops-extensions

I have been trying in vain to make Azure DevOps Office Integration with excel.  It was working previously, but stopped spontaneously.

Symptom:
Excel crashes after selecting the organization/project (right before it should show me the queries). This only is happening for the main [company] organization I connect to, but I've found I *can* still successfully pull queries from a random organization I created years ago into excel. So the plugin itself seems to be working, but I can't get into the organization I need to.  The authentication dialog does come up and it pings my authenticator app as one would expect, but Excel goes down immediately after. I have no difficulty accessing this ADO Organization from VS (2022) nor the web interface.

No error messages are shown, excel just closes. Windows event viewer shows:
Faulting application path: C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\root\Office16\EXCEL.EXE
Faulting module path: C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Team Foundation Server\17.0\Microsoft.WITDataStore64.dll
Exception code: 0xc0000005
Fault offset: 0x000000000003b780

**Tried so far:**

- Full repair of MS 365 Office.
- Reinstalled plugin, confirming latest version
- Remove and add back the servers in Excel add-in
- Checked Credential Manager for anything that looked related to devOps--didn't find anything.
- Cleared caches below  ------c:\users\yourlogin\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Team Foundation
  ---c:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft shared\Team Foundation Server
  ---c:\users\yourlogin\AppData\Local\Temp\Microsoft\Team Foundation
- Everything on this page:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/backlogs/office/tfs-office-integration-issues?view=azure-devops#office-add-in-doesnt-load-or-open-in-excel-when-visual-studio-fail
- Deleting HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\VSCommon\14.0\ClientServices\TokenStorage\VisualStudio\VssApp
- Applying all pending updates to VS 2022.
- Clearing %LOCALAPPDATA%.IdentityService
- Many Reboots.

Notes:
I am onsite at my workplace and connecting to the services with no problem everywhere else, so VPN/AD should not be an issue here.
Everything is 64 bit.

Comment: To narrow down the cause of the issue, have you tried to connect ADO via the plug-in on any other machine or connect any other ADO organization that is backed with the same Tenant? Does anyone else in the same organization encounter the same issue?